# CSS border styling fitting content

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble fitting some content into a border. When entering more text, instead of extending to fit vertically it just continues past the border as shown in the attached screenshot:[image]

And my CSS file is as follows:

```css
body {
    background-image:url(http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;

    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    font-size: 8pt;
}
#content {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #A2B964;
}
#banner {
    height: 50px;
    background-image:url(http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/bannerbg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#banner img {
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#general {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
dl {
    margin: 10pt;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
}
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10pt;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    margin-left:0px;
}
#leftsection {
    width: 550px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url(http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
#rating {
    height: 83px;
    background-image:url(http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/hsafa/cmps278/hw2/rbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#rating img {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.special {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 48pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
.review {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #E8DC9B;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
.personal {
    margin-bottom: 20pt;
}
.italic {
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
img.review {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#leftcol {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: left;
    width: 47%;
}
#rightcol {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: right;
    width: 47%;
}
#pages {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 5px;
}
#validated {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left:80%;
    width: 600px;
}
#validated img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I've added the HTML code on CSSDeck:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/bldwwaec

Comment: It is hard to know what is what in your CSS without the HTML code. Adding a link to a demo at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs) or a similar site also makes it easer and faster to help you.

Comment: could you post your html code?

Comment: try adding "overflow:auto" to your containing div.

Comment: parent container should be float:left, #content{float:left}

Comment: `clear: both` on `#pages` would fix the overflowing issue. But you probably want to change the way the green background is applied then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you put the HTML codes too.

The right side element is either `fixed` (or `absolute`) or `float`. If it is float, you can simple fix it with adding a `<br />` at the end of its parent element and set `clear: both;` on it. Like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div class="float-right">bbbb</div>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Now, the `div#parent` fits with the content and if you set a border on it, your problem would fix.

In `absolute` case, however, it is not as easy as I explained and recommend revising the use of `absolute` (or `fixed`) for that part.

Good luck,

[Mohammad Ali Sharpasand](http://m.a.sharpasand.com/)

Comment: The clearing worked but now my left section is having the same problem even though they're both contained in the same parent

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/PtcihDN.jpg?1

Comment: A parent will not change the child's height.  You can do one of the following:
1. put all the left part into one div and set it on absolute with `top: 0;`, and `bottom: 0;` and change the position of `content` to `relative`.

2. put both of the left and right parts in the same `div` and set the background of right part to it so that the background would scale with the right one. Also the page numbers can be after the `<br />` so at the bottom.

The latter is better as it don't use `absolute` and `relative`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the floating right column.

```css
#rightcol {
    float: right;
}
```

It would appear you need to clear the `float`, since floating elements are removed from normal page flow, the parent element will not expand to match the height. A simple solution is to add a `clearfix` to your parent element or class (in our case ID)

```css
#content:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

This should solve your issue, if you have more questions about this I would suggest [looking here.](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for my right section but now my left section doesn't extend anymore

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/PtcihDN.jpg?1

Answer (score 1):

you have to put one more div over the id=content and you can call the calss=pagewrapper.

```css
.pagewrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

put `float:left` in your ID

```css
#content{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course today, float is no longer needed, as the flexbox is available:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Also, grid is amazing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids