# Fit content inside the border

Tags: html, css

Just wrote some newbie css kind of code. I don't know how to fit the image inside the border! I want to fit the water icon inside the circular border! Please run the snippet below

```css
.notice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #f3fff2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
  border-left: 4px solid #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.notice:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: -17px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.info {
  border-color: #e4ffe0;
}

.info:before {
  content: url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/water-droplet-icon-72075.png');
  background-color: #e4ffe0;
}
```

```html
<div class="notice info">
  <p>This is a an info notice, it provides feedback of a neutral nature to the user.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153603/css-border-styling-fitting-content  see this link I think It will help to you

Comment: Why are you repeating things 3 times? Why are you repeating things 3 times? Why are you repeating things 3 times?

Comment: 'cause it said "you question mostly contains code" so i didnt know what to write so i copy pasted it 3 times :) Lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use content image as a `background`...it will be easy for you to control the size of image

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.notice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #f3fff2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
  border-left: 4px solid #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.notice:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: -17px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.info {
  border-color: #e4ffe0;
}

.info:before {
  content: "";
  background: #e4ffe0 url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/water-droplet-icon-72075.png') center/20px no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class="notice info">
  <p>This is a an info notice, it provides feedback of a neutral nature to the user.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in as a background?

```css
.notice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #f3fff2;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
  border-left: 4px solid #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.notice:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: -17px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.info {
  border-color: #e4ffe0;
}

.info:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e4ffe0 url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/water-droplet-icon-72075.png') no-repeat center/contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="notice info">
  <p>This is a an info notice, it provides feedback of a neutral nature to the user.</p>
</div>
```